# SAS dates: format the quarter as year/quarter

Tags: date, sas

I have a data set with SAS date format "01JAN1980". I want to generate a variable called "quarter" with format "1980Q1" or what ever combination of year and quarter.
Here is what I my SAS codes:
    quarter=QRT(date)
    format quarter yyq.

but it gives me 1960Q1 instead of 1980Q1.

Does any one know where is the problem?

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 5):

The Quarter function returns the quarter number, i.e. 1-4. SAS interprets this as a date with a value of 1, which is equivalent to 1st January 1960, then displays that date in yyq. format. So what you actually want here is just to make a copy of the original variable, without changing the value, and apply the format: `quarter = date; format quarter yyq.;`.

Also, in some cases you might not even need to make a copy of the variable - you can place a `format` statement in the middle of most procs and it will use that format for the output of the proc.